# New Serenity deployment failing on Azure with Invalid object name 'Languages'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, serenity-platform

Using Serenity framework v 5.0.24.
I have a new solution with a small demo of something, all works locally but when I tried to deploy it to an Azure resource it seems to be failing to even create the database, but I can't figure out why. 'Languages' is the second thing in the initial migrations unit so I'm assuming its that.
I've deployed dozens of serenity apps before on previous versions so I'm not a newcomer.
Here's the raw exception output:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Languages'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Serenity.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(IDbConnection connection, String commandText, IDictionary`2 param, ILogger logger)
   at Serenity.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(IDbConnection connection, SqlQuery query, ILogger logger)
   at Serenity.Data.EntitySqlHelper.ForEach(SqlQuery query, IDbConnection connection, Action callBack)
   at Serenity.Web.RowLookupScript`1.GetItems()
   at Serenity.Web.LookupScript.GetScript()
   at Serenity.Web.DynamicScriptManager.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<EnsureScriptContent>g__factory|0()
   at Serenity.TwoLevelCacheExtensions.GetInternal[TItem](ITwoLevelCache cache, String cacheKey, TimeSpan localExpiration, TimeSpan remoteExpiration, String groupKey, Func`1 loader, Boolean localOnly)
   at Serenity.TwoLevelCacheExtensions.GetLocalStoreOnly[TItem](ITwoLevelCache cache, String cacheKey, TimeSpan localExpiration, String groupKey, Func`1 loader)
   at Serenity.Web.DynamicScriptManager.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<EnsureScriptContent>g__getOrCreate|1()
   at Serenity.Web.DynamicScriptManager.EnsureScriptContent(String name, IDynamicScript script)
   at Serenity.Web.DynamicScriptManager.GetScriptText(String name)
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__LayoutHead.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Projects\research\distanceSignOff\distanceSignOff.Web\Views\Shared\_LayoutHead.cshtml:line 21
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.RenderPartialViewAsync(TextWriter writer, Object model, IView view)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__LayoutNoNavigation.<ExecuteAsync>b__9_0() in C:\Projects\research\distanceSignOff\distanceSignOff.Web\Views\Shared\_LayoutNoNavigation.cshtml:line 7
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__LayoutNoNavigation.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Projects\research\distanceSignOff\distanceSignOff.Web\Views\Shared\_LayoutNoNavigation.cshtml:line 5
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at StackExchange.Exceptional.ExceptionalMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at StackExchange.Exceptional.ExceptionalMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:f3bf9b09-8ec0-45dd-b2e3-28445db434a9
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
ClientConnectionId before routing:6066e64d-1796-4b10-bf92-233e7990242a
Routing Destination:aed1b953e0aa.tr14046.eastus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11009
```

Comment: How does the database get installed on server?   The location or credentials may not be correct.  Is this first time you are installing on a Window 10 machine?  Is first time you are installing with Core?  What is different this time from previous times?

Comment: it's deployed to a WebApp resource on Azure, which is fine because it's running. The database is SQLServer also on Azure. I can log into the database. I cannot determine any difference from times I've done this action before. I have tried removing all resources and adding again. If the credentials are wrong I get a specific error telling me that. If the firewall is wrong I get a specific error about it. I've just never seen this happen on  a serenity deployment as they are usually seamless.

Comment: You have front end (client to server) and a backend (server to database).  When you got errors in past were they front end of backend?  When you run SSMS are you running on the server?  When you got errors in past were you running inside VS.  VS does not automatically run As Admin.  You need to right click on VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  This looks like a credential issue, not sure where in the front/back that the issue is occrring.

Comment: thanks for your input, but this is all in-cloud Azure stuff, no admin or credentials problems. I have answered my own now with the actual resolution.

Comment: I got you "thinking outside the box".  You were just looking at the error and not remembering the Migration Safety Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I've found my own problem.
I had overlooked the removal of the the migrations safety check in `DataMigrations.cs` around line 203, the part that stops you writing new databases willy-nilly.
I remember (maybe) in the past the application would warn you that migrations had been skipped rather than just pull exceptions on the first SQL object not found.
Easily done, but I feel a bit daft!